# Access unallocated space of HDD

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, filesystems, operating-system

How can I access and write to the unallocated space of a Hard Disk Drive, from Windows ?

By unallocated HDD space I'm referring to the space that remains on the HDD after partitions have been created, or just free space on the HDD that has not been assigned to a partition.

Comment: Anybody cares to comment on why downvotes for a perfectly valid question?

Comment: [This may be relevant](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100027), if you've not already come across it. Short answer: in XP and older versions of Windows, this is eminently possible. In newer versions, you'll need to write driver-level code to do this. Depending on your use-case, it may just be easier to use a host operating system like Linux.

Comment: any learning materials on filesystem driver-level concepts,code etc?

Comment: You can start reading about Windows Driver Kit ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487428.aspx ). You need a kernel-mode driver of any type - your goal is just to get into kernel mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read the partition table of the hard disk, find the unallocated space, then read that space. Such operations require direct access to disk. Before Vista it was possible to call CreateFile("special name of the disk itself") to open the disk like a file. In Vista and Windows 7 it's not possible anymore due to security restrictions of Windows (at least for non-admin account). You can use our [RawDisk](http://www.eldos.com/rawdisk/) product to access disk sectors for reading and writing in Vista and later systems. Note, that RawDisk includes a kernel-mode driver which needs administrative rights to be installed (which rights are not always available).

Comment: Hum? I have RW sector-level access in Windows 7 through XxxxFile API, including sectors of unallocated space.

Comment: @zapador if you have admin rights, you can access the disk for reading. Writing afaik is forbidden even for admins.

Comment: Admin privileges are needed but I'm sure I'm writing the 63 sectors of the first track of a disk with a bootloader from user mode app, in Windows 7. I don't know if it would work in Vista.

Comment: @zapador Did you try to do the same outside of the IDE? Did it work? For most people this doesn't work due to security restrictions. Maybe this also depends on some hotfix.  I have updated the answer. Also it would be interesting to hear from you about testing your code outside of the IDE.

Comment: Yes, in fact it works in hundreds of PCs, both XP and Windows 7 SP1.  Maybe something changed between versions or updates. I use HxD as disk editor I think it doesn't need kernel mode code either.  I have not tried to read/write blocks of an umounted volume. Hope it helps.

Comment: @zapador It did work on XP and then stopped working on Vista. Maybe they've rolled back the restriction with some update to Windows 7. However it works only for admins which is not always acceptable.